# how to convert Enum to IEnumerable<SelectListItem>

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, html-helper

**UPDATE 1**

I want to populate a `listboxfor` mvc helper to render list items in View. I don't know how to pass the second parameter to the helper, which accepts `IENumerableSelectListItem` `SelectionList`.

```
 Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.SelectedDate, Model.DateList, new { })
```

I am having a property in my model class,

```
public IEnumerableSelectListItem  DateList { get; set; }
```

and somehow i need to populate **DateList** from my controller action method, which fills up all the other model properties and passes it to a partial view where i have the helper. DateList should be getting the values from an Enum DateListEnum

Any ideas on how to go about doing this. Also let me know how do i ensure that a single list item is selected at a time...i am really new to all these..and its been quite some time i am working on this...but nothing came up so far....

I am having below code in my controller action method,

```
model.DateList = getDateList();
```

which calls this method,

```
public IEnumerableSelectListItem getDateList()

{

IEnumerableSelectListItem  values = Enum.GetValues(typeof(DateListEnum));

 //this one doesn't work because of casting issues and this is where i want to convert Enum Values to  IEnumerableSelectListItem

return values; 

 }
```

**UPDATE 2**

i have the listbox working and its displaying in the UI based upon below code

```
` IEnumerable<SelectListItem> values = Enum.GetNames(typeof(ColumnFormattingDateFormats)).Cast<ColumnFormattingDateFormats>().Select(p => new SelectListItem()
            {
                Text = p.ToString(),
                Value = ((int)p).ToString()
            }).ToList();`
```

But now i am having few other problems,

the enum that i am using is

```
`public enum ColumnFormattingDateFormats : int 
{ 
[StringValue("Wednesday, March 14, 2001")]
 FULLDATE = 0, 
[StringValue("3/14")]
 MMDDWSLASH = 1,
 [StringValue("3/14/01")]
 MMDDYYWSLASH = 2,
 [StringValue("03/14/01")]
 MMDDYYWMMZEROPREFIXWSLASH = 3 
}`
```

and my helper looks like this,

`Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.SelectedDate, Model.DateList, new { })`

**1> How do i pass the selected item to the listboxfor helper?**
is there a way to pass the selected item to the helper through the property
 `[DataMember]
 public ColumnFormattingDateFormats SelectedDate{ get; set; }`
 in my model class? to begin with i am passing
 `this.SelectedDate= ColumnFormattingDateFormats.FULLDATE;` 
to the default constructor in my model class...but for some reason the first parameter `model => model.SelectedDate`has some problem with that..throws null exception...

**2> how do i ensure `[StringValue]` from Enum gets displayed in UI listbox element and not the Enum Text for ex. FULLDATE should not be getting displayed, instead "Wednesday, March 14, 2001" should be?**

**3> How do i ensure that a single item is selected without using livequery?**

My brains are all fried up now....any directions anyone?????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about:

```
Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnum))
.Cast<MyEnum>()
.Select(p => new SelectListItem()
                    {
                        Text = p.ToString(),
                        Value = ((int) p).ToString()
                    })
                .ToList();
```

Comment: `Cast<My Enum>` still throws an error **is a method, which is not valid in the given context**

Comment: okay...this is solved now...but have one more issue with, `Value = (int)p` which says **cannot implicitly convert type int to string**

Comment: this is my enum,`public enum ColumnFormattingDateFormats : int
    {
        [StringValue("Wednesday, March 14, 2001")]
        FULLDATE = 0,
        [StringValue("3/14")]
        MMDDWSLASH = 1,
        [StringValue("3/14/01")]
        MMDDYYWSLASH = 2,
        [StringValue("03/14/01")]
        MMDDYYWMMZEROPREFIXWSLASH = 3 }` if this helps...

Comment: sorry corrected myanswer, I write this in one editor then make changes in VS and copied wrong one :), hope it helps

Comment: is there a way to pass the selected item to the helper which is contained in the property `[DataMember]
        public ColumnFormattingDateFormats SelectedDate{ get; set; }` in my model class? to begin with i am passing `this.SelectedDate= ColumnFormattingDateFormats.FULLDATE;` to the default constructor in my model class...but for some reason the first parameter `model => model.SelectedDate` has some problem with that..throws null exception...